# kivy image not reloading

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am writing a code for taking image and display this image in next window.
first screen will display the camera and second screen will display the taken image.

I try changing source to image name but it's not reload after image taken. May be cache problem.
delete this image cache but it's not working

Here is my code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
import kivy
from PIL import Image
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from working.transform import four_point_transform
from skimage.filters import threshold_local
from kivy.loader import Loader
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import imutils
kivy.require('2.0.0')
Builder.load_string("""
<CameraScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        play: True
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'camera'
        text: 'Capture'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
        on_press: 
            root.capture()
            root.callback_image_address('corp.jpg')
       
        on_release:
            root.manager.current='settings'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'


<SettingsScreen>:
    Image:
        id: main_image
        source: root.image_source
        size: self.texture_size
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: 'Back to Camera'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .03}
        on_press: 
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

# Declare both screens
class CameraScreen(Screen):


    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        imgname='page.jpg' # Change imge name to "IMG.png"
        #chage test.jpg to imgname
        # don't have to know what's the code is
        # just make sure this below code corp the document
        camera.export_to_png('test.jpg')
        image=cv2.imread(imgname)
        ratio=image.shape[0] / 500.0
        orig = image.copy()
        image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
        edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)
        cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
        for c in cnts:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
            if len(approx) == 4:
                screenCnt = approx
                break
        warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
        warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        T = threshold_local(warped, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
        warped = (warped > T).astype("uint8") * 255
        # warped file is main file to display in the main software.
        #cv2.imshow("Scanned", imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
        #Save corp document
        cv2.imwrite('corp.jpg',warped)

    def callback_image_address(self,new_image_address):
        if new_image_address:
            settingscreen=self.manager.get_screen('settings')
            new_image_address='corp.jpg'
            settingscreen.callback_image(new_image_address)
        
       

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    image_source = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def callback_image(self, new_image_address):
        sm.current = "settings"
        self.img = new_image_address
        self.ids.image_source.source = self.img

class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        global sm 
        sm= ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(CameraScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Method I try:-
[Kivy: changing image source on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868637/kivy-changing-image-source-on-screen)